# Carousel plugins conflicting with 'type: privileged'

Tags: javascript, carousel, firefox-os

In my Firefox OS app, I want to use XHR, so I have `type` set to `privileged` in the manifest file.

The carousel plugins that I have tried so far: [Jssor](http://www.jssor.com/) and [Scooch](http://mobify.github.io/scooch/), both did not work when this type was set. I tested it in Firefox OS simulator v2.0. The image in the carousel is rendered, but it’s not allowing me to slide it.

How do I fix this?

**EDIT:**

Error in the console: `Error: call to eval() blocked by CSP` pointing to angular.js

Comment: I'm aware that this question is old, but which version of angular were you using? The CSP thing could be a check made by angular that isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

This means that your plug-in is trying to use eval() function in JavaScript which is blocked by security FirefoxOS, I would recommend using some other plug-in to avoid using the eval function.

You can read more about the security policy at [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/installable_apps_for_Firefox_OS/CSP).

Answer (score 0):

As Rodrigo says, the problem is the use of **eval()** on your Javascript libraries. The use of **eval()** gets a block in the Javascript used on privileged webapps, so the webapp stop working as it should be.

This blocking was made by security issues that can produce **eval()** with Javascript. If you are planning to push your app to the Firefox Marketplace your app will be rejected by that reason. You can use the [validation app on the Firefox Marketplace](https://marketplace.firefox.com/developers/validator) to check what kind of CSP blocking (and other issues) could have your privileged app.